# How to generate id with specific pattern - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm looking for an optimised method to generate an id with a specific pattern, for my case I want invoices id to be like "FA00001, FA00002... FA00003..."

I found a solution, but it's a little bit **weird**

First in Ruby you need to know that the pattern i need are generated by something like this:

```
puts "FA%05d" % 1    # will return FA00001
puts "FA%05d" % 1251 # will return FA01251
```

So for generating the id before creation on the instance i call this method:

```
def generateId
    lastId = Invoice.last&.id
    return lastId.next if lastId != nil     # return the next FA value 
    return "FA%05d" % 1                     # return FA00001 if NO invoice in database
end
```

in my controller it work like this:

```
@invoice= Invoice.new(invoices_params)
@invoice.id = generateId
@invoice.save
```

This is my probleme i hope you have a better and more sexy method

**EDIT:** (2023)
This weird solution is very prone to race condition so it's unsable.
I don't remember how we solve this in 2020. but i remember that we need to save id with this pattern in database.

Comment: This code is extremely prone to race conditons. You really want to use an autoincrementing column or sequence in the database. Why not just use the id and pad and prefix it with `FA`?

Comment: `@invoice.id = ...` can be problematic. A model's [`id`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey.html#method-i-id) attribute has special meaning. It returns the primary column's value which is usually an integer (that will be set automatically). Although you can configure it to be a string, it's easier to follow the conventions. Save yourself some trouble and use another attribute like `reference_number`.

Comment: One option is to use [String#succ!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-succ-21): `s = "FA00008" #=> "FA00008"; s.succ! #=> "FA00009"; s.succ! #=> "FA00010"; s.succ! #=> "FA00011"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is prone to race condition. If two clients will try creating Invoice simultaneously - one will at least get an error, in the worst case both will get same id.

Actually by default you already get unique integer autoincremented `id`, so easiest is just to format it:

```rb
class Invoice
  # ...
  def formatted_id
    id && ("FA%05d" % id)
  end
end
```

(note that `id` and everything that uses it will be available on model instance only after it was successfully saved)

Comment: after some years i came to answer you,

This don't solve our problem because we need this id in database